# Why this linq query doesn't return distinct code?

Tags: c#, linq

I want list of all unique Scheme_Codes but I am unable to write query. I tried this one but I am confused what's problem with this query.

```
 var queryresult = db.MFData.GroupBy(x => new { Scheme_Name = x.Scheme_Name, Scheme_Code = x.Scheme_Code, FundFamily = x.FundFamily, Date = x.Date })
                   .Select(group => new
                   {
                       Scheme_name = group.Key.Scheme_Name,
                       Scheme_Code = group.Key.Scheme_Code,
                       FundFamily = group.Key.FundFamily,
                       Date = group.Max(x => x.Date),
                       count = group.Select( x =>  x.Scheme_Code).Distinct().Count()
                   }
                   ).OrderBy(x => x.Scheme_Code);
```

I have this query but I am not sure how to convert this to linq

```
SELECT [Scheme_Code],[FundFamily],[Scheme_Name],
 MAX([Date]) as LastDate   
 FROM [MFD].[dbo].[MFDatas]   
 GROUP BY [Scheme_Code],[Scheme_Name], [FundFamily]  
 ORDER BY [Scheme_Code]
```

Comment: your both queries are different

Comment: Please add the "specific problem or error" that you are having with your current solution. Do you get an error? If yes, which one? Does it return the wrong result? If yes, what is the actual and the expected result?

Comment: I want to convert last sql query to linq. so I tried to write first one. and I am getting diff output. I want to convert 2nd sql query to linq. I want all unique scheme_codes but linq gives something diff

Comment: You'll get closer if you remove `Date` from `GroupBy`

Comment: how can I retrieve date then?

Comment: I am trying, will tell you it's result in 2-3 mins, thanks @Ivan Stoev

Comment: @IvanStoev I am trying to run that query as you said but it is taking more than 10 mins to run, my database size is 3GB. Any solution for it?

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev , It's working but I have to find out way to optimize it.   People have marked this question as negative. :( So Can't ask it here anymore.

Comment: @Nil If this is EF, you can see the generated SQL query by `var sql = var queryresult.ToString()` and see what you got. Unfortunately, there are not many (if any) choices to optimize EF LINQ query because the generated SQL totally depends of the query provider translator, and you cannot fool it by using nested queries etc. (the typical SQL optimizations)

Comment: The LINQ query line `count = group.Select( x =>  x.Scheme_Code).Distinct().Count()` (which is actually missing in the original SQL query) causes generating quite inefficient SQL query, and also does not make any sense - since the `Scheme_Code` is included in your `GroupBy` key, it will always return 1. So either remove it, or if you really *want list of all unique Scheme_Codes*, why don't you use simply `db.MFData.Select(x => x.Scheme_Code).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x)`.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is omit the date from your groupby-clause:

```
var queryresult = db.MFData.GroupBy(x => new 
    { 
        Scheme_Name = x.Scheme_Name, 
        Scheme_Code = x.Scheme_Code, 
        FundFamily = x.FundFamily 
    }).Select(group => new
    {
        Scheme_name = group.Key.Scheme_Name,
        Scheme_Code = group.Key.Scheme_Code,
        FundFamily = group.Key.FundFamily,
        Date = group.Max(x => x.Date),
        count = group.Select(x => x.Scheme_Code).Distinct().Count()
    }).OrderBy(x => x.Scheme_Code);
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot ! Any other way to optimize this query? It takes more than 10 mins to execute